# Is there a single member of the Einzbern family who is a human being?

Tags: fate-stay-night, fate-zero

From the information I could find, nearly all known members of the Einzbern family are (female) homunculi (Justeaze, Irisviel, Illyasviel and all the maids), the only exception being Jubstacheit, who is supposed to be an A.I. controlling an array of humanoid golem bodies.

Is there any information on Einzberns who are actually human beings? Are there any alive at all at the time of the events of Fate/Zero and Fate/Stay Night? If there is not, can the Einzberns actually be considered a "bloodline" in the strict sense of the word, or are they more like an army of self-cloning homunculi?

Comment: considering he was married into the family you may consider Kiritsugu as an Einzbern since Ilya is his daughter but he is no longer alive in the Fate/Zero universe and we aren't entirely sure if the Einzbern Bloodline is the exact same in Fate/kaleid (as apparently there was only one Holy Grail War and that was stopped before hand by Kiritsugu and Iris)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Einzberns from the beginning were a factory of homunculi. Per the booklet released alongside the DVD for the Unlimited Blade Works anime:

> • **The origins of Einzbern**
>
> A factory originally created by the students of the magician who
>   realized the third magic. Began in the year 1 AD.  They attempted to
>   reproduce their master’s miracle, but couldn’t do it themselves, so as
>   an alternate plan they tried to recreate a specimen identical to their
>   master and have it reproduce the magic.
>
> After nearly 900 years of effort, Justeaze—the homunculus who would
>   come to be called the Winter Saint—was forged.  She was a model that
>   strayed from what the magi had intended, created completely by
>   accident, but her abilities were equal to or above those of their
>   master.  The magi should have been elated about Justeaze, but they
>   couldn’t be happy. After all, she was a mutation that was born
>   regardless of their own techniques or skills.  Even if that specimen
>   was to reproduce the third magic, that conclusion would be harder for
>   them to bear than 900 years of failure.
>
> The magi deperately attempted to create a homunculus that excelled
>   Justeaze by their own techniques.  The artificial intelligence created
>   to act as the castle’s central management—the golem Jubstacheit—was
>   the pinnacle of their craft, and became the father of all homunculi
>   created at Einzbern.
>
> Justeaze succeeded at proving the third magic.  However, it was not
>   cost-effective. Justeaze’s use of the third magic was like careful
>   knitting. It would take several years to save just one person, making
>   the salvation of the entire human race virtually unattainable.  In
>   addition, while Justeaze herself did not age, her body was so frail it
>   would take little to kill her, so she could not leave the castle. 
>   Since her intelligence and mentality were also unaging, she did not
>   develop at all. From an outside perspective, it was as if she was
>   repeating a single day for all eternity.  If she were to leave the
>   castle she would be freed from this “single day,” but the act of
>   leaving the castle signified an easy death for Justeaze.
>
> In the end, they accepted that humans could create something that
>   surpassed humans, but not something that could save humans. … Or
>   perhaps they would not have failed if a miracle like Justeaze had not
>   occurred.
>
> The magi despaired the limits of their abilities. Some abandoned the
>   castle, while others took their own lives.  The homunculi left at
>   Einzbern were abandoned by their creators, but in their purity, they
>   continued to operate the factory for the sake of the creators’
>   ideology—the salvation of humankind, the reproduction of a miracle.
>
> From then on, all homunculi created at Einzbern were based off of
>   Justeaze.  Jubstacheit created a humanoid terminal unit, and used it
>   as the manager of Einzbern. Though by the end he operated even Acht
>   (the eighth humanoid terminal), he did not possess a personality.  He
>   only included the necessary “humanity” to operate the castle and
>   reproduce the third magic into each of his humanoid terminals, and
>   made them act like humans.  Jubstacheit is essentially an automaton
>   that cannot progress, but continues operating in perpetuity. His way
>   of existence is just like an old clock ticking away, being forgotten
>   by people before running down.